# define "com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY" somewhere else?

Tags: java, android, xml, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

In the current Google Android Maps documentation, the "com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY" is defined in the manifest file. Is there a way to define it to somewhere else? like in the util or java class file?

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start#get_an_android_certificate_and_the_google_maps_api_key

Add the API key to your application

Follow the steps below to include the API key in your application's manifest, contained in the file AndroidManifest.xml. From there, the Maps API reads the key value and passes it to the Google Maps server, which then confirms that you have access to Google Maps data.

In AndroidManifest.xml, add the following element as a child of the  element, by inserting it just before the closing tag :

```
<meta-data
    android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
    android:value="API_KEY"/>
Substitute your API key for API_KEY in the value attribute. This element sets the key com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY to the value of your API key, and makes the API key visible to any MapFragment in your application.
```

Save AndroidManifest.xml and re-build your application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there a way to define it to somewhere else? like in the util or java class file?

No, because Play Services will be looking for it in the manifest.

Now, AFAIK, you are welcome to define the *value* of the API key in a string resource that is in your `res/values/` directories with the rest of your strings. You also should be able to use stuff like the placeholder system in manifest merging to define the API key in your `build.gradle` file.

Comment: so that means whoever has the apk can unzip it, get the manifest, and figure out the Google Android Maps API key? is there a way to obscure the api key?

Comment: @user1190695: "so that means whoever has the apk can unzip it, get the manifest, and figure out the Google Android Maps API key?" -- sure. Since it is useless to them without your signing key, there would be no point. "is there a way to obscure the api key?" -- no.

Answer (score 0):

No you cant set the Api key programmatically 
but if you need to use map and you migh need to change that api key you can do some trick like add some webView and fill it webBased GoogleMap